# How to calculate a sum which implicates sets

Tags: combinatorics, summation

So the set $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and $P(A)$ the set of the parts of $A$. And $f : P(A)\to \mathbb{N}$ the function which associates to each subset of $A$ its cardinality. Calculate  $$\sum_{E\in P(A)}f(E)$$

How do you begin this ?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^6 \binom{6}{i}i$

Comment: What are the possible values for the cardinality of a subset of $A$? And for each of those values, how many different subsets have that cardinality?

Comment: Well the cardinality is 6 ?

Comment: Do you mean that $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$, the set of all subsets of $A$?

Comment: P(A) represent all of the parts of A. Does this make sense ?

Comment: What I am asking is if by parts you mean subsets?  The set $B$ is a subset of $A$ if each element of $B$ is also an element of $A$.

Comment: Oh, that I don't know to be honest. The only thing that I know is what I already gave you. The question has something to do with an identity implicating binoial coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *power set* of $A$, denoted $\mathcal{P}(A)$, is the set of all subsets of $A$.  The number $f(E)$ represents the number of elements in subset $E$ of $A$.  Thus, the question is asking you to calculate the total number of elements in all the subsets of the six element set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Let's consider subsets of set $A$ of size $2$.  They are 
$$\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 4\}, \{1, 5\}, \{1, 6\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{2, 5\}, \{2, 6\}, \{3, 4\}, \{3, 5\}, \{3, 6\}, \{4, 5\}, \{4, 6\}, \{5, 6\}$$
As you can see, there are $15$ of them.  Let's see why.  We have six ways to pick the first element of the subset from set $A$ and five ways to pick the second element, which must be distinct from the first.  However, since the set $\{1, 2\} = \{2, 1\}$, the order in which we pick the two elements does not matter.  Thus, the number of subsets of size $2$ is 
$$\frac{6 \cdot 5}{2} = 15$$
Notice that the number of subsets is 
$$\frac{6 \cdot 5}{2} = \frac{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{6!}{2!4!} = \binom{6}{2}$$
the number of unordered selections of two elements from a set of six elements.

More generally, the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $6$ elements is 
$$\binom{6}{k} = \frac{6!}{k!(6 - k)!}$$
To see why, observe that we can choose the first element of a non-empty subset in $6$ ways, the second element in $5$ ways, and so forth.  We can pick the $k$th element in $6 - k + 1$ ways.  Hence, the number of ordered selections of $k$ elements from set $A$ is 
$$6 \cdot 5 \cdots (6 - k + 1) = 6 \cdot 5 \cdots (6 - k + 1) \cdot \frac{(6 - k)!}{(6 - k)!} = \frac{6!}{(6 - k)!}$$
However, we could have selected those $k$ elements in $k!$ orders, so the number of subsets of size $k$ that can be selected from set $A$ is $$\frac{6!}{k!(6 - k)!} = \binom{6}{k}$$
Since there are $\binom{6}{k}$ subsets with $k$ elements, the number of elements in the subsets of size $k$ is therefore $$k\binom{6}{k}$$  Hence, the number of elements in all the subsets of set $A$ is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{6} k\binom{6}{k}$$

Comment: I don't understand why I was given such a question which is out of my level to be honest... Does 6*$2^5$ make any sense ?

Comment: You should have $$\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k} = \binom{6}{0} + \binom{6}{1} + \binom{6}{2} + \binom{6}{3} + \binom{6}{4} + \binom{6}{5} + \binom{6}{6}$$  Try calculating that.  Let me know what you obtain.

Comment: I obtain 1+6+15+20+15+6+1=64

Comment: That is correct.  Observe that $64 = 2^6$.  The reason the sum is $2^6$ is that for each subset, we have two choices for each of the six elements in set $A$, to include it or not include it.

Comment: So this is the answer ? I spent way too much time on this problem and it feels like you just did my work x( (Not that it's bad, of course lol)

Comment: I misread the question.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking your time. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set of ordered pairs $(x,E)$ where $x\in A$, $E\in P(A)$, and $x\in E$. Each $E\in P(A)$ occurs as the second component in $f(E)$ of these pairs, one for each $x\in E$.  So the total number of pairs under consideration is $\sum_{E\in P(A)}f(E)$, the sum in your question.

Fortunately, there is an alternative way to count the total number of pairs under consideration.  Each of the six elements $x\in A$ is the first component of $2^5=32$ of these pairs, because $x$  isan element of $2^5$ subsets $E$ of $A$. (The reason is that, to form such a subset, we have two options for each of the five elements of $A$ other than $x$; each such element can be put into $E$ or kept out.  Two options for each of 5 elements gives $2^5$ options altogether.) So the total number of pairs under consideration is $6\cdot32=192$.

Equating the two ways of counting the same set of pairs, we get $\sum_{E\in P(A)}f(E)=192$.

Comment: An alternative way of saying the same thing, less detailed but perhaps easier to grasp: Think of $f(E)$ as a sum of a bunch of $1$'s, one $1$ for each element of $E$. Then each of the $6$ elements of $A$ contributes a $1$ to $f(E)$ for 32 of the sets $E$. So the total number of contributed $1$'s is $6\cdot32=192$.

Comment: Someone else told me 192 but I wasn't sure

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. The sum at the end of it is $0+6+30+60+60+30+6=192$.  The reason I posted a separate answer is that I like this type of proof based on counting the same set in two ways, and it involves less arithmetic than the binomial coefficient approach.  It's good to learn both techniques.

Comment: ah ok thank you i just noticed that